# Getting the full name of a Snowflake resource in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working with a large and complex Terraform codebase that target Snowflake. One of the conventions is to always fully qualify names (database and schema). Very often, I see and use this pattern:

```
statement = "select * from ${snowflake_table.some_resource_with_a_very_long_name.database}.${snowflake_table.some_resource_with_a_very_long_name.schema}.${snowflake_table.some_resource_with_a_very_long_name.name}"
```

This makes the code quite difficult to read. Isn't there a way to improve on this somehow?

- In other languages, I would just define a function and do `"select * from ${fully_qualified(snowflake_table.some_resource_with_a_very_long_name)}"` but Terraform evidently does not allow user defined functions
- I don't want to create `local.fully_qualified_some_resource_with_a_very_long_name` because the locals namespace is polluted enough as it is in my complex module

Is there no way to just ask a Snowflake resource for its fully qualified name?

Comment: You probably can using null_resource or something similar, but I don't think you can do it in an argument defined in another resource. Resource references is just how things work. Additionally, I would say that naming convention is an issue on your side, not terraform. :) The same applies for locals.

Comment: Agreed that the naming convention doesn't help here, but unfortunately I cannot change it in my case.